# Why am getting null value from ArrayList after adding value using thread

Tags: java, collections

I run the following code multiple time and found that sometime I get "null" from ArrayList. I am not able to understand why this happening with me while I am adding Integer value to array.

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class test implements Runnable {

    static List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new test());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new test());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println(ls.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < ls.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println(i + "  " + ls.get(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
                ls.add(i);
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
36  
0  0  
1  0  
2  1  
3  1  
4  2  
5  2  
6  3  
7  3  
8  4  
9  4  
**10  null**   
11  5   
12  6   
13  6  
14  7   
15  7   
16  8  
17  8  
18  9  
19  9  
20  10  
21  10  
22  11  
23  11  
24  12  
25  12  
26  13  
27  14  
28  15  
29  16  
30  16  
31  17  
32  17  
33  18  
34  19   
35  19
```

I know the why the total size is 36. But I want to know that why i got null at 10th position.

NOTE: This is not generating on every time. You may have to run this code 5 to 10 time to generate this.

Comment: Do you know how `ArrayList` resizes internally? Just don't use thread unsafe objects across threads.

Comment: "Just don't use thread unsafe collections across threads." It is not relevant. @Pillar

Comment: Please look into the semantics of `synchronized`. You're using it wrong. `run()` method is almost never `synchronized`.

Comment: @sub Why don't you think so? Do you mean I should clarify with _thread unsafe objects without external synchronization_? That was implied.

Comment: It may be interesting to know "how come integer auto boxing product null or y ArrayList#add add null except 5" beside following happy path.

Comment: I am sorry about the run method synchronized. I also understand that the size 36 because of ArrayList  is un synchronized class. But I want to know that while I am adding some value at any index then how it can became null.

Comment: `synchronized` run would work if you had a single `test` object.

Comment: `synchronized` *might* work in a particular case, and it's sure handy when it does, but it isn't really a *general* solution.  Inter-thread design is going to have to be an explicit part of your application's total architecture.  You must see to it that the logic never "races," "deadlocks," or "starves."

Comment: No, it's really *not* an answer, Subhrajyoti.  Not at all!  You see, the other thread could have been modifying the data structure at any point.  The logic that's "iterating through it, to copy it," could stumble into an inconsistent pointer-value and crash.  There's no "safe and predictable way" to do this ... **none(!)** ... without proper mutual-exclusion.

Comment: "The get must've accessed before the elements were copied over." how come??? its very clear ArrayList#get is accessed in main thread after both thread finishes their work. Agree with @MikeRobinson that must not be the case.

Comment: `ArrayList#add` internally does `elementData[size++] = e;`. And as this operation is not atomic so what happened first thread incremented the index and before value assignment second thread increments index. Then both assign the value at same index. It could be possible to easily identify with some concrete class object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are encountering is something called a **race condition.**

The "race" is happening *within the Java runtime library code* that implements the collection-object that you're using.  (And, so far, you have been *extremely lucky* that it didn't bring your entire program crashing down. Next time, it easily might ... The situation is *unstable.*)

If you intend to use container classes among threads, you **must** ensure that the classes you use are ***"thread-safe,"*** which means that they contain the necessary logic to allow them to be correctly used by multiple threads at the same time.  **Or,** you must manually implement appropriate mutual-exclusion logic throughout your application.  (The main thread must interlock with the child thread so that it does not attempt `ls.get()` while the thread is simultaneously doing `ls.add()`.)

If the class you're using *isn't* thread safe, sometimes you'll see an application defining a "wrapper class" of its own devising which "wraps" calls to the not-thread-safe class in mutual-exclusion logic of its own devising, so that the wrapper "is" thread-safe, at least for the purposes of the application.

*(P.S.:* This principle applies to any programming language.)

Answer (score 3):

The relevant quote in the Javadoc is:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally [adding or removing elements], it must be synchronized externally.

But you *are* using synchronization, by making the `run()` method `synchronized`. So something isn't right.

Making an instance method `synchronized` is like wrapping the method body in `synchronized (this) { ... }`. The issue is that `this` is different in each of the threads, so they don't execute the block mutually exclusively: the effective behaviour is no different with or without the `synchronized`

Instead, add an explicit `synchronized` block, using the list as the monitor:

```
public void run() {
  synchronized (ls) {
    // Your method body.
  }
}
```

Alternatively, your current code can simply reuse the `test` instance in both threads:

```
test t = new test();
Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
Thread t2 = new Thread(t);
```

This approach means that `this` is the same in both threads, so the synchronized block is mutually-exclusively executed. It would also work here, but is a brittle strategy in general, since you could create another thread with a new test instance, meaning the same issue would recur.

Note that both of these solutions would mean that the entire loop would execute for one thread before the loop for the other thread. Effectively, it just behaves like executing everything in one thread. This is because the monitor is acquired before the loop starts, and released after it finishes: the operations can't interleave between the threads.

Another alternative is to make the list synchronized:

```
List<Integer> ls = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

This wraps the unsynchronized list so that each individual operation on the list is executed in a `synchronized` block. This *would* allow the operations to interleave, since the only mutually exclusive section is the call to `ls.add`, not the entire loop.